# Putting uneditable, static text inside of an input[type=text] field (screenshots)

Tags: html, css, input, styling

I am developing an app where users can choose the URL of their profile, ala facebook.com/name.  Everything worked out fine, except I'm having styling issues adding a static set of text inside the input, to help convey the message of having your own URL.

**Here's what I want the input to look like when the user is visiting the page:**
[image]

**And here's what I want it to look like when they add their own input:**
[image]

Half of this problem is easy, I can just set a large left-padding to the input, get it to display hover effects regardless of where the mouse is and place the input accordingly.  But the issue is getting the text into the input line without breaking the styling around it (and preventing the user from being able to select the static text, so that even clicking the static text will "focus" the input field behind it).

I'd really prefer to use pure HTML/CSS, but could use Javascript if it's a must.

Here's where I am now, the goal is to bring the "www.website.com" text into the input field without breaking the styling of the textarea to follow: http://jsfiddle.net/rUkS8/1/

Thanks and sorry for such a long description!

Comment: Define a _div-element_ to get your visible _border_. Make the base url static as text in a _span-element_. Add a textinput to the right and disable all styling for the input-field.

Comment: Not sure that's an advisable UI pattern. Users will naturally expect that anything in the input is editable. Similar implementations I've seen show the "full" string adjacent to the input and update it dynamically based on the content entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not bypass the problem and simply have that static text outside of the input?

```
www.website.com/<input type="text" name="url" />
```

This degrades nicely in older/brain dead browsers, works when javascript is disabled, and makes it obvious where the seperate of inputs is.

Comment: This was my first idea, too. I recommended to use a div with border and a input without any styling to achieve the wanted styling, too.

Comment: I've tried this, got some flack from the rest of the UX team who didn't like the way it broke the styling/flow of the page

Comment: Then simply trap 'change' events (blur, keyup, etc...) and check each time if the required text is present. If it's not, then add it back in. This is even WORSE design, but if looks trump useability, then you're stuck with obeying the looks people, at the cost of making life hell on the users.

Comment: Alright I switched to a more standard setup, input field with a string updating on keyup showing the final string.  Hopefully it's intuitive!

Comment: @MarcB you can put the suggested solution in the comments as an option in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a label and the `for` attribute, it will handle the click events for you:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000;">
    <label for="textinput" style="cursor:text;">asdf</label>
    <input type="text" id="textinput">
</div>
```

If you click on the label, it will send the focus to the input.  Putting `cursor:text;` adds to the effect.  All you have to do is play games with size and border and you're all set.